# How to get month in FSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I 'm using pod FSCalendar( https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) and to localise it I use :

```
 calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: String)
```

but the problem is that last few letters in translated month grammatically sounds not good.( It's like   "of December 2016 "   instead of just   "December 2016 "  in wanted language )
On storyboard I have only UIView, could you please help to understand what exactly answer for month in this pod? 
As I understood I can do smth like this

```
 if monthLabel.text.hasPrefix("") {
 monthLabel.text = //change to normal

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Russian locale in FSCalendarHeaderView.m change function

- (void)configureCell:(FSCalendarHeaderCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

for this

```
- (void)configureCell:(FSCalendarHeaderCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FSCalendarAppearance *appearance = self.calendar.appearance;
    cell.titleLabel.font = appearance.headerTitleFont;
    cell.titleLabel.textColor = appearance.headerTitleColor;
    _calendar.formatter.dateFormat = appearance.headerDateFormat;
    BOOL usesUpperCase = (appearance.caseOptions & 15) == FSCalendarCaseOptionsHeaderUsesUpperCase;
    NSString *text = nil;
    switch (self.calendar.transitionCoordinator.representingScope) {
        case FSCalendarScopeMonth: {
            if (_scrollDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal) {
                // 多出的两项需要制空
                if ((indexPath.item == 0 || indexPath.item == [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0] - 1)) {
                    text = nil;
                } else {
                    NSDate *date = [self.calendar.gregorian dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth value:indexPath.item-1 toDate:self.calendar.minimumDate options:0];
                    text = [_calendar.formatter stringFromDate:date];
                }
            } else {
                NSDate *date = [self.calendar.gregorian dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth value:indexPath.item toDate:self.calendar.minimumDate options:0];
                text = [_calendar.formatter stringFromDate:date];
            }
            break;
        }
        case FSCalendarScopeWeek: {
            if ((indexPath.item == 0 || indexPath.item == [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0] - 1)) {
                text = nil;
            } else {
                NSDate *firstPage = [self.calendar.gregorian fs_middleDayOfWeek:self.calendar.minimumDate];
                NSDate *date = [self.calendar.gregorian dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear value:indexPath.item-1 toDate:firstPage options:0];
                text = [_calendar.formatter stringFromDate:date];
            }
            break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }
    }

    NSArray* foo = [text componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
    NSString* firstBit = [foo objectAtIndex: 0];

    if ([firstBit isEqualToString:@"января"]) {
        firstBit = @"январь ";
        text = [firstBit stringByAppendingString:[foo objectAtIndex: 1]];
    }
    if ([firstBit isEqualToString:@"февраля"]) {
        firstBit = @"февраль ";
        text = [firstBit stringByAppendingString:[foo objectAtIndex: 1]];
    }
    if ([firstBit isEqualToString:@"марта"]) {
        firstBit = @"март ";
        text = [firstBit stringByAppendingString:[foo objectAtIndex: 1]];
    }
    if ([firstBit isEqualToString:@"апреля"]) {
        firstBit = @"апрель ";
        text = [firstBit stringByAppendingString:[foo objectAtIndex: 1]];
    }
    if ([firstBit isEqualToString:@"мая"]) {
        firstBit = @"май ";
        text = [firstBit stringByAppendingString:[foo objectAtIndex: 1]];
    }
    if ([firstBit isEqualToString:@"июня"]) {
        firstBit = @"июнь ";
        text = [firstBit stringByAppendingString:[foo objectAtIndex: 1]];
    }
    if ([firstBit isEqualToString:@"июля"]) {
        firstBit = @"июль ";
        text = [firstBit stringByAppendingString:[foo objectAtIndex: 1]];
    }
    if ([firstBit isEqualToString:@"августа"]) {
        firstBit = @"август ";
        text = [firstBit stringByAppendingString:[foo objectAtIndex: 1]];
    }
    if ([firstBit isEqualToString:@"сентября"]) {
        firstBit = @"сентябрь ";
        text = [firstBit stringByAppendingString:[foo objectAtIndex: 1]];
    }
    if ([firstBit isEqualToString:@"октября"]) {
        firstBit = @"октябрь ";
        text = [firstBit stringByAppendingString:[foo objectAtIndex: 1]];
    }
    if ([firstBit isEqualToString:@"ноября"]) {
        firstBit = @"ноябрь ";
        text = [firstBit stringByAppendingString:[foo objectAtIndex: 1]];
    }
    if ([firstBit isEqualToString:@"декабря"]) {
        firstBit = @"декабрь ";
        text = [firstBit stringByAppendingString:[foo objectAtIndex: 1]];
    }

    text = usesUpperCase ? text.uppercaseString : text;
    cell.titleLabel.text = text;
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Comment: This is the only way to localize it on Russian - works perfect

Answer (score 2):

Quick Solution in Swift 3

First inherit the FSCalendarDelegate then add this...

```
func calendarCurrentPageDidChange(_ calendar: FSCalendar) {

    let currentMonth = calendar.month(of: calendar.currentPage)
    print("this is the current Month \(currentMonth)")
}
```

This "currentMonth" will change everytime you scroll the calendar per month.

Comment: Value of type 'FSCalendar' has no member 'month', How did you get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, FSCalendar has wrong implementation - it is sth. like using locale.calendar.monthSymbols instead of locale.calendar.standaloneMonthSymbols

Quick soultion is to fix FSCalendar code in file FSCalendarHeaderView.m

```
(void)configureCell:(FSCalendarHeaderCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    case FSCalendarScopeMonth: {
        //...
        //...
        text = [_calendar.formatter stringFromDate:date]; //**1
    }
}
```

**1 must be changed to sth. like

```
NSDateComponents *cc = [self.calendar.gregorian components:(NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear) fromDate:date];

text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %ld", _calendar.formatter.standaloneMonthSymbols[cc.month - 1], (long)cc.year];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily and nicely with the following code:

```
//objc
self.calendar.appearence.headerDateFormat = @"LLLL yyyy";

//swift
self.calendar.appearence.headerDateFormat = "LLLL yyyy"
```

**To learn more about dates formatting use table from** http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Answer (score -1):

```
var locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ru_RU")
calendar.locale = locale as Locale
```

Comment: Hello, to help others understand your answer, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the posted question.

Comment: Why would you use NSLocale and then cast it as Locale, instead of directly using Locale? There's really no point in doing that. // Also, as Henry said, it's not clear how your answer addresses OP's issue.